# Spring Boot Integration Testing addViewController

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, integration-testing

I am trying to do an integration test on my configuration file that uses addViewController.
The configuration file looks like this

```java
@Configuration
public class MVCConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
    }

}
```

So far I got to this point with the integration test

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MVCConfiguration.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MVCConfigurationTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void addViewControllers() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(view().name("forward:/index.html"));
    }
}
```

The assertion error is resulting in a 404 error and I'm getting a "org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping for OPTIONS /" error in the logs.